# How to prove that the zero sum game's optimal (security) strategy do not change when payoff matrix increase by a constant factor

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, game-theory

I am not sure how to construct a proof for something so obvious, can someone give me some pointers on proving the following

> Suppose a constant K is added to each element of a pay-off matrix
>   related to a game. What effect will it have on the solution?
>
> (a) The optimal (security) strategies of the players and the value of the game remain
>   unchanged.
>
> (b)    The optimal (security) strategies of the players do not change
>   while the value of the game will increase by K.
>
> (c)    The optimal (security)
>   strategies of the players as well as game value will all change.
>
> Prove assertion.

So we have a payoff matrix $A$, we add a constant $k$ to each element $A$ yielding $A + K$. Our optimal value (value of the game) is $J^* \in A$, since $A$ is increased by $k$, therefore $J^*$ is increased by $k$.

Finally, our optimal (security) strategy for original payoff matrix $A$ is by choosing maximum payoff for player 1 when player 2 picks the lowest payoff, and choosing the lowest payoff (lowest cost) for player 2 when player 1 picks the maximum payoff. Since adding a constant does not change the well orderness of each row or column, therefore the security strategy remains the same as before.

Is there anything I could do to make more argument more rigorous for this intuitively obvious result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The argument can not be made more rigorous than it is now. It is an illusion to think that adding mathematical notation would make some argument more rigorous.

Comment: The solution is incomplete. It doesn't consider mixed startegies

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt to give an rigorous solution:
let $x$, $y$ be the mixed strategies used by player 1 and 2. Let $E(x,y):= \sum_i\sum_jx_ia_{ij}y_j$ denote the payoff function. Then for the new game, the payoff function is given by, \begin{aligned}E*(x,y) &= \sum_i\sum_j(a_{ij}+k)x_iy_j \\ &= k + \sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}x_iy_j \\ &= k + E(x,y)\end{aligned}
Now its clear that $\max_x\min_yE*(x,y) = k + \max_x\min_yE(x,y)$.
Now both parts follow.